# How to scale a Geom_bar to be in line with an overlaid line graph in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to overlay a bar chart with a line graph on a single plot with ggplot in R. My line graph works fine but the data are much larger than the data for the bar chart component.

How could I use an additional scale for this bar chart or do something that will get this to look nice all in one graph.

Here is my plot code thus far:

```
chart <- data.frame("QuantileName" = 1:5, "AvgLoss" = c(100, 500, 1000, 2500, 3000), "AvgFactor" = c(1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5))

Plot <- ggplot(chart, aes(x = 1:5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Quintile", limits = c(0, 5 + .5), breaks = seq(1, 5)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = AvgLoss, colour = "AvgLoss")) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = AvgFactor, colour = "AvgFactor" ), stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = AvgLoss,  label = round(AvgLoss)), position = position_nudge(x = .3)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = AvgLoss)) +
  ylab("AvgLoss") + 
  scale_colour_manual("",breaks = c("AvgLoss","AvgFactor"), values = c("AvgLoss" = "red", "AvgFactor" = "grey")) +
  ggtitle("Quintile Plot") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
Plot
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Essentialy, multiply your `AvgFactor` variable by a number

`+ geom_bar(aes(y = AvgFactor*1000, colour = "AvgFactor" ), stat = "identity")`

and set

`+ scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./1000, name = "AvgFactor"))`

so your plot code would look like

```
Plot <- ggplot(chart, aes(x = 1:5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Quintile", limits = c(0, 5 + .5), 
                     breaks = seq(1, 5)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = AvgFactor*1000, colour = "AvgFactor" ), 
           stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(aes(y = AvgLoss, colour = "AvgLoss")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = AvgLoss,
                label = round(AvgLoss)), 
                position = position_nudge(x = .3)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = AvgLoss)) +
  ylab("AvgLoss") + 
  scale_colour_manual("",breaks = c("AvgLoss","AvgFactor"), 
                      values = c("AvgLoss" = "red", "AvgFactor" = "grey")) +
  ggtitle("Quintile Plot") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./1000, name = "AvgFactor"))
```

However, I think it is probably more elegant to avoid secondary axes whenever possible.

It may be useful to know that `geom_col(...)` is shorthand for `geom_bar(..., stat = 'identity')`